# После объявления переменной в условии IF она недоступна в программе

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql

Переменная типа `string Query` создается под `If` конструкцией, пишет дальше по коду, что она не существует.

Как это исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста, без проверки нельзя создавать ее (Query)...

```
if ((Combobox1.Text == "Машина") && (IsStuffCheckBox.IsChecked == true)) 
{ 
    string Query = "INSERT INTO Transport (IsIn,IsStuff,Indif,Baggage,Time) VALUES('" + Convert.ToString(this.IsInCheckBox.IsChecked) + "' , '" + Convert.ToString(this.IsStuffCheckBox.IsChecked) + "')"; 
} 
SQLiteCommand CreateCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query(<--ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА), sqliteCon);
```

Comment: @Sergey_Yysmaa, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Sergey_Yysmaa](/users/33291/sergey_yysmaa), естественно. Вы объявляете переменную в блоке `if`. Снаружи одна не видна. Это называется "область видимости". Чтобы она была видна снаружи, объявите ее перед `if`-ом.

Comment: Ну и глупый же я:) Спасибо!